# True/false in linear algebra exam : inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I found a true/false exam. Here is the exercise (other question are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864325/true-false-linear-algebra-exam-spectral-of-composed-function):

2) Let $q(x)=x^7+1$. Set $W=\{p(x)\in \mathbb R_n[X]\mid p(0)=0\}$. Let $r(x)\in W$. Suppose $$\int_0^1 (q(x)-f(x)p(x)dx=0,$$
for all $p(x)\in W$. There is $s(x)\in W\backslash \{r(x)\}$ such that
$$\int_0^1 (q(x)-s(x))^2dx< \int_0^1 (q(x)-r(x))^2dx.$$

2) Let $\mathbb C^5$ the space with the weighted euclidian inner product with weight $(2,1,3,1,4)$. Let $S\in \mathcal L(\mathbb C^5)$. Suppose $\det S=2-i$. There is $v=(v_1,...,v_5)\in \mathbb C^5$ such that $$2|v_1|^2+|v_2|+3|v_3|^2+|v_4|^2+4|v_5|^2\neq 2|w_1|^2+|w_2|+3|w_3|^2+|w_4|^2+4|w_5|^2,$$
where $S(v)=(w_1,...,w_5)$.

---

My Answers:

1) I would say TRUE. But I have problem to prove it rigorously. I thing $\int_0^1 pq$ is a scalar product. Therefore, there is a unique $r$ s.t. $<q-r,p>=0$ for all $p\in W$. Now I tried to prove that $\|r-s\|^2=0$ to get the contradiction $r=s$, but I have problem to do it.

2) Since $\det(S)=2-i\neq 0$, then $S$ invertible. We have that $$\|S(v)\|^2=\|w\|^2=2|w_1|^2+|w_2|+3|w_3|^2+|w_4|^2+4|w_5|^2\neq 2|v_1|^2+|v_2|+3|v_3|^2+|v_4|^2+4|v_5|^2=\|v\|^2,$$
and thus, $S$ is not an isometry. But I don't get any contradiction anywhere. So I need help here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why the downvote ? Not enough effort ? Sometimes this website is strange... I spent a half hour to write all that, I tried to explain what I did, and after someone downvote. What the hell ! what's wrong  with these people??

Comment: I don't get the downvote, either. If I had to guess, maybe something wrong with the title. It would be helpful to specify what $\mathcal F (X,Y)$ and $Spec (T)$ are.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: thank you for your comment :) It's difficult to do better since question are in different topic. But thank you anyway for your support.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to break this into separate questions?

Comment: @MichaelBurr : It would take 2 hours since I can't ask more that one question in 20 minutes.

Comment: There's a reason for that limitation, MSE. Subverting the rules is frowned upon.

Comment: I edited my question : it should be better now.

Comment: (1) Is false. Assume that $r$ is the orthogonal (with respect to that inner product) projection of $q$ onto $W$. Then $\|q-r\|\leq\|q-s\|$ for all $s\in W$. In particular, there is not going to be an $s\in W\setminus \{r\}$ such that $\|q-s\|$ is strictly less than $\|q-r\|$.

Comment: For (2) is there a typo in that weight $3$? It looks like you are using weight $4$ afterwards for the third component. If that weight is a $4$ then is the same idea as in your linked question. Since $|det(S)|=\sqrt{3}>1$ there must be an eigenvalue with absolute value strictly larger than $1$. Take $v$ to be an eigenvector for that eigenvalue.

Comment: @nextpuzzle: It's 3 (not 4), I correct it. And thank you for 1.

Comment: Well, since the inequality wanted got corrected from weight $4$ to weight $3$, then the answer is the same.

Comment: @nextpuzzle: Sorry but I really don't understand in what I can conclude (for 2)

Comment: @nextpuzzle: So the answer is yes, right ?

Comment: Since the product of the eigenvalues is $>1$ there is at least one of them $r$ with $|r|>1$. Then if $v$ is an eigenvector for $r$, it follows that $\|Sv\|=\|rv\|=|r|\|v\|\neq \|v\|$.